# Replacing old work triple switch

Tags: switch

My house has all old work 1970. No grounds that I’ve seen yet. My issue is I have a trickle switch where one controls the porch one controls, the dining and one controls the outside light the one that controls the tiny the dining room is also controlled by a switch on the opposite wall, I bought this triple switch thinking it would work because I couldn’t see the wiring in the back. There’s a lot of wires in this old work and not a lot of wires on this new switch. Some of them are jumped on the old work.

It’s all old sheets wiring with no metal jackets or anything. The boxes are not metal though this old switch seems to have some kind of metal jacket on it.

These houses have single wall construction. I’m in Hawaii.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the top of the three old switches is a three-way switch that works with the one on the other side of the room.   The new triple switch that you have there is just three regular switches. It won't work. A triple switch with one three-way is harder to find, but legrand makes one and maybe others. Buy one of those, do not disconnect any wires from the old switch until you have a new one, then very carefully study and compare the two switches. The new one will go in exactly like the old one except that where the old one has three screws down one side strapped together with one wire, the new one will have just one screw instead of the three, and you'll need to cut the excess bits off that wire.

The grounding of the new switch will be no better or worse than the old one. I don't know what you mean by sheets wiring, but if you take a better lit picture of the inside of the box showing the cables entering the box, we might be able to say a little more about grounding.